# How to run code 24/7 from cloud

Tags: python, cloud, data-collection

My intention is to run python code 24/7 over several months to collect data through API calls and alert me if certain conditions are met.

How can I do that without keeping the code running on my laptop 24/7? Is there a way of doing it in "the cloud"?

Preferably free but would consider paying. Simplicity also a plus.

Comment: Does anyone know why the question may have been downvoted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I'm not sure what in that long list you're pointing at but I see nothing wrong here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Please let me know how to ask the question so I can get an answer. I'm new to coding but I asume it's a fairly basic and hence easy question.

Comment: "How can I do in a cloud?" is a "Chatty, open-ended question". Please show what have you tried and why you have problem with that.

Comment: I got a helpful answer below but I'm going to have to delete the perfectly genuine question and its perfectly helpful answer before I get more downvotes. It seems I can no longer delete it. I guess I'll have to wait for the downvotes to come.

Comment: @phd As I started to program web apps, I just didn't know where to start and had the same open and broad questions. Sometimes one just needs to get general understanding. And some time later the questions will become better.

Comment: If you don't know where to start why not start with [asking Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=cloud+hosting)?

Comment: Of course Google is always an option for every question on StackOverflow, including the most technical but my understanding is that the point of the site is not having to do a ton of research over something that others already know about and can resolve in five seconds. Incidentally, I wouldn't have thought of using the word "hosting" in this context. That could have been helpful in an answer too.

Comment: Meta FAQ [disagrees](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/7976758). "Ask a question on Stack Overflow as a last resort!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plenty of free possibilities. You can use [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) servers. They have a strong documentation for python and is free (but of course with limit on megabytes and time usage). Heroku is also good because they have a lot of extensions (databases, dashboards, loggers etc.). In order to deploy your app on heroku you need to have some experience of working with git (but not that much, don't worry).

Another possibility could be Google Cloud Platform, which should be also easy to use.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I had the same problems some time ago as I started to program some little apps,